# Why is my web server adding a line to my source code?

Tags: coldfusion

This question as first asked was closed by three experts who were convinced that the source code displayed by the browsers had to be the same as the code which I uploaded to my web host server. I knew that this was not the case, therefore the problem must lie with my web hosting ColdFusion server, as it is highly unlikely that all three browsers would make the same mistake.

My page (https://gustav-mahler.org/nachrichten/pdfs.cfm) begins like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
```

However in Chrome 80, MSIE 11 and Firefox 73.0.1, the source code is displayed like this:

```
--->
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
```

I am now suspecting that the string "--->" must have been added by my ColdFusion webserver for some reason, as that string normally indicates the closing of a ColdFusion comment. But in this case there is no comment to close. I have added a ColdFusion tag to this question, and if this problem is unknown to CF experts, I shall have to ask my web host technician for advice.

Comment: Does this happen in your development environment?

Comment: You are correct that the string `--->` is part of a ColdFusion comment. You must have that somewhere in your code base without the preceeding `<!---` comment. Remember that ColdFusion may be processing several files in order to generate that one HTML template. The problem could be in any of those including the Application.cfc file.

Comment: Thank you, Miguel, for reminding me that these comment pairs can get separated and end up on different pages! Since I have a few thousand comments in my website, I'd better start looking now! @Dan Bracuk I don't run CF locally, I do all my testing on the host server, but now I'm going to assume that the problem is local!

Comment: Can you use your code writing software to do a text search for `--->`?  If not, can you download the file and do a text search with Notepad?

Comment: If you have an `application.cfm` or `application.cfc` they can be injecting that code. See if one of them has it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very long comment that tells you how to find the source of the problem.

On the host server, create an html page with a doctype tag, plus opening and closing html, head, and body tags.  Add a short paragraph, inside `p` tags.  Browse the page and check the html source for the extra line.

If it's there, talk to your hosting company.  Otherwise, rename the file from .html to .cfm.  Browse and check again.

If the line is not there, it's likely your code.  Start adding lines of ColdFusion code, one or two at a time and keep testing until the line appears.